# I have ubuntu linux 32 and need to change to 64. My processor will handle 64. I upgraded to 18.04.1

Tags: upgrade, 64-bit

This is my first time posting.
I need to do the above upgrade. 
I am not very tech savvy; a friend switched me from windows to linux some yrs ago.
I am familiar with using the terminal a bit.
Can someone please advise how to do the upgrade?

Comment: I would suggest a re-install.  If you use the 'something else' option you can select your partitions and select not-to-format, which is what I would do.  The no-format option causes main system directories to be erased & re-created anyway, but the process will at the end try and re-install the programs/apps you had installed in the first place, and since your data wasn't touched - most things should remain the same.  It won't handle 3rd party programs (from ppa's etc), but should handle standard repository programs.  Backup your data first anyway, and ensure you have format unchecked.

Comment: Thank you. Your info is more complicated than my experience allows me to pursue.

Answer (score 0):

You should completely reinstall your OS to move from 32 to 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks. I just have to figure out how to do that very thing.

Comment: I would suggest you to try it on Btrfs file system where you will be able to make a snapshots to which you will be able to turn back in case something wrong will happen. You can create a new thread with asking to help how to install an Ubuntu from zero.